# How to properly sign a winmd file?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, signing, strongname

We are shipping a signed Windows Runtime Component. Currently we sign the winmd like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\sn.exe -R MyComponent.winmd mykeypair.snk
```

This requires a hardcoded path at worst(assuming you're using 64-bit to build and have exactly v8.0A).. or at best requires an environment variable to be setup before you can do a build

In Visual Studio, there is also a section on the Windows Runtime Component's Project page called "Signing". If I check the signing box though and choose an appropriate keyfile, it'll appear to work fine, but won't be properly signed:

```
sn -vf MyComponent.winmd

Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.17929
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

MyComponent.winmd is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly
```

I've found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581658/using-a-winmd-library-causes-a-strong-name-validation-exception) references to this [problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0f39b267-095b-49e0-9c67-8ba875a58635/how-to-strong-name-sign-a-winmd-file), but never have seen an actual bug report or acknowledgement that it's an actual issue.

The reason we want to ship a signed component, as opposed to unsigned is that we want our component to be capable of being used from other strong-named components. If our component was unsigned, this would not be possible.

Is there a better workaround for this issue, or am I doing something wrong that's causing signing not to work as I expect?

Comment: Larry Osterman was pretty explicit about it, .winmd files cannot be signed.  Nor is there any point to it.  Why do you insist to try anyway?

Comment: @HansPassant he didn't say they couldn't be signed because they can, they pass certification and their restrictions will be upheld as well(at least with test mode or whatever).  Even if you were not intended to sign then, why leave the menu in Visual Studio then?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing an MSBuild target to hack it together so that it signed the WinMD file just after compilation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="SignWinMD" AfterTargets="ExportWindowsMDFile" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(SDK40ToolsPath)\sn.exe&quot; -R &quot;$(_IntermediateWindowsMetadataPath)&quot; $(AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

You include it in your project by simple adding this somewhere before the `</project>` tag

```
<Import Project="SignWinMD.targets" />
```

After doing this, your project will be properly signed when using the `Signing` menu from the Project page of the component in Visual Studio. Note you must have a key setup for this to work.